# Passing a YAML frontmatter variable from a page to a collection in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

So i have a collection called `components`. The components are a series of small HTML objects with some data in.

I want to pull these components into a page, and be able to pass overriding YAML frontmatter from the page into the component to determine a couple of things on the component.

Is this possible?

I'm pulling specific components onto a page using the following syntax:

```
{{ site.components | where:"component_name","event-title" }}
```

but i'd like to be able to do something like:

```
{{ site.components var-page-state="offline" | where:"component_name","event-title" }}
```

I chose to use a collection than a series of includes, as i need to loop through the collection and generate/render an index page of all of the components on it automatically.

EDIT:

So i want my component to be able to output a variable set on the page it's included on.

*component.title.html:*

```
<h2 class="title">{{ page.var-page-status }}</h2>
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to do. Can you show an example of a component, and what you want the output to be?

Comment: I've updated it with a snippet of a component.

Comment: Why do you need to pass this to the component? The page you're on can just render it by itself, right?